# Using NSMutableURLRequest to POST a HTML form (specifically the 'checkbox' control)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I know there are lots of tutorials on this, and I've mostly got it working. There is one problem, though, and that's with the checkbox. The control has a name attribute of `Confirmation`. It also has a value of `Yes`.

So I set my key to `Confirmation` and I set my value to `Yes` but this doesn't work. I've also tried setting the value to `On` and `checked` since I've seen online that they are often used as well. Nothing.

The way I sort out the request is by creating an NSMutableDictionary, setting the keys/values, then looping through them setting NSMutableData in the form `KEY=VALUE&`, and then setting the request's `setHTTPBody` to the NSMutableData.

I'm aware of the ASI library, this is legacy code so I'm just going with it for now.

Comment: Have you snooped what the actual form sends using the debugger in Chrome/Firefox/Opera et. al.?

Comment: Yeah, it sends `Confirmation: Yes`, which is somewhat confusing...